# how to display result from json to textbox

Tags: jquery, html, json

i have a textbox to display data from json file. when i type in textbox, i want to display data with criteria as "autocomplete". but when i trace with firebug. and i get return in tab Response/HTML like this  :

```
{"rajaongkir":{"query":[],"status":{"code":200,"description":"OK"},
"results":[
{"province_id":"1","province":"Bali"},
{"province_id":"2","province":"Bangka Belitung"},
{"province_id":"3","province":"Banten"},
{"province_id":"4","province":"Bengkulu"},
{"province_id":"5","province":"DI Yogyakarta"},
{"province_id":"6","province":"DKI Jakarta"} 
{"province_id":"7","province":"Sumatera Selatan"},
{"province_id":"8","province":"Sumatera Utara"}
]}}
```

and this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() { 
    $( "#kotaAsaljne" ).autocomplete({ 
     source: "city.php",
     minLength: 3,
     search: function( event, ui ) {     
      $( "#kotaAsaljne" ).val(0);
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) { 
      if (ui.item) { 
          $( "#kotaAsaljne" ).val(ui.item.province);
      } else {
          $( "#kotaAsaljne" ).val(0);
      } 
  }
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
from : <input type="text" name="kotaAsaljne" id="kotaAsaljne"/> 

</body>
</html>
```

please help me... 
Thanks !

Comment: what issue you have facing please post clear question?

Comment: the problem does not show the value of the textbox with autocomplete function

Comment: JQuery UI autocomplete support source as an array of objects with label and value properties. So you need to change the format either on server side or on client side

Comment: please give me solution of 'client side', thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom function as source and manipulate the data come from server.

Try this :

```
$(function () {
    $("#kotaAsaljne").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'city.php',
                data: {search: request},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.province,
                            val: item.province_id
                        };
                    }));
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log("error",response);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            // your on select callback
        },
    });
});
```

I hope it will help you.
Refer here for more info on function source 
https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Any error in console? Provide full detail what is not working